# Encountering problems with Installing Sage

Tags: software-installation, sagemath

I am trying to install sage but hit problems when I enter "apt-get update" and consequently "apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary." What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to install Sage.  You may wish to try the [Ubuntu PPA](http://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html) - but note the special instructions for command line:

```
sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```